# How to refresh the whole scope

Tags: angularjs

I try to implement authentication in a mobile app. Basically the user clicks on a button, that opens a URL in an InAppBrowser which is closed when the authentication is done. Then I refresh the current user by calling a REST URI. Finally I refresh the `$scope` with the new data. The issue is that not the whole scope is refreshed.

`$scope.user` is refreshed but not `$scope.userLoggedIn` which depends on `$scope.user`.

```
resolve: {
    user: ['User', function (User) {
        return User.current(function (user) {
            return user;
        }, function (error) {
            return {};
        });
    }
    ]
},
controller: function ($scope, $window, user, $translate, $parse) {
    $scope.user = user;

    $scope.redirectTo = function (path) {
        var x = $window.open(path, '_blank')
        x.addEventListener('loadstop', function(event) { 
            // $scope.$apply(function(){ //let angular know the changes
                alert('loadStop: ' + event.url); 
                var url = event.url;
                var filename = url.substring(url.lastIndexOf('/')+1);
                if(filename == "mobile.login.html"){
                    x.close();
                    alert("refresh current user");
                    user.$current(function (data) {
                            alert(data);
                            $scope.user = data;
                            alert(data);
                            alert($scope.userLoggedIn);
                        });
                }
        //  });
        });
        //$window.location.href = path;
    };

    $scope.userLoggedIn = $scope.user.profile !== undefined;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I managed to make it work. I need to use `$watch` to monitor the changes to `$scope.user`.

```
$scope.$watch('user', function(newValue, oldValue) {
    alert("New Value" + $filter('json')(newValue));
    alert("Old Value" + $filter('json')(oldValue));
    $scope.userLoggedIn = newValue.profile !== undefined;
    alert("user changed " + newValue.profile + " " + $scope.userLoggedIn);
});
```